# How to unwrap a model with every polygon facing the view?

Tags: uv

How to unwrap a model with every polygon facing the view in the "UV Image editor" window? An alternative to this is to align every polygon one by one to the view in orthographic view and one by one to unwrap it with "U|Project from view bounds". But instead of doing it one by one, is there a faster way?

Comment: And if possible, every polygon not to intersect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get a similar effect by making all edges of the mesh 'Seams' and doing a normal unwrap.

1. Enter Edit mode on selected mesh
2. Select all edges
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> Mark Seam
4. <kbd>U</kbd> > Unwrap

[image]

Selected faces show that face shapes are preserved in UVs.

Comment: And by doing this, every polygon is as it is in the 3d view right? I, mean, do they have the same shape as in the 3d view?

Comment: @Vladimir Added a new image with more complex face shapes to show they are indeed preserved.